# php create an rss feed (lets say for a poll website)

Tags: php

How do i create my custom RSS feed generator with php ?

Hopefully i will like to avoid use of any libraries(if possible).

Lets say i have a poll website where users create polls.

lets say I want to record the events :
1)when people create a poll a function will get provoked containing the code ti write RSS to XML file.
etc etc events.

Lets i want to record 3 things:
1)username of the user who created the poll contained within a variable lets say `$username`.
2)The text of the poll lets contained in the variable `$text`
3)The options : an array containing all the options lets say the name of the array be $options

How do i write it maybe using the DOMelment function in php ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why avoid libraries? Something like [`Zend_Feed_Writer`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.writer.html) can save you tons of work.

Comment: Well libraries reduces customization

Comment: In the highly unlikely case where you need to customize anything, you can just extend their classes.